# CSS Menu overlap

Tags: html, css

I am trying to build a menu using CSS.This is what i have done so far

[Js Fiddle Code](http://jsfiddle.net/QP6u4/)

The problem i am facing is when the width of browser decreases the menu items start to overlap as

[Js Fiddle Code](http://jsfiddle.net/QP6u4/1/)

What could be the possible solution that the items don't overlap rather are displayed in the next line

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What I would do is this: instead of a separate class for the selected item in the menu I'd use a `menuItem selected` instead, and have the menuItem float to left

check out [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QP6u4/2/)

Comment: thanks for the reply...can the distance between both the lines of menu be increased?